# CMD not recognizing javac.exe

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java, environment-variables

On my Windows 7 64 bits, I changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable to point on 64 bits JRE, and changed it again to point on 64 bits JDK. I did same operation a few times.

Every time I do this change I close and open the cmd again .

[image: Screen capture of my env variables]

Note that same settings were working before.

Any idea of what's happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Any idea of what's happening?

`JAVA_HOME` should point to the root directory of your Java installation:

```
setx JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

You also need to add the Java bin directory to your path:

```
setx PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;%PATH%
```

See [Installing the JDK Software](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html#CHDEBCCJ) and [Setting JAVA_HOME and PATH and CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for more information.

Comment: I defined both as system variables and not user variables. and did what you mention. It works now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that it worked before - had you `cd`'d into `%JAVA_HOME%`?

If you want the programs in the `bin` folder to be accessible from anywhere in a command prompt, you need to add it to your `PATH`. Since you don't have a user-specific `PATH` variable yet, create one, and set its value to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin`. Then you'll be able to enter `javac` on a command prompt anywhere and it will work.

Also, correct values of the `JAVA_HOME` variable *do not* end with `bin`. ([Source.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)) That may affect other programs that try to use Java.

Comment: Please see my comment for DavidPostill answer. thanks.